# I can't show arabic on my website, do I have an encoding issue?

Tags: c#, encoding

I've tried this code on an arabic page :

```
    tmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmlDoc = hw.Load(@"http://www.reciter.org/KATHEER/002002.html");
    if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
    {
            Response.Write(htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tr/td").InnerText);
    }
```

And the result was something like this  : ������ �
 
How can I resolve this?

**Update :**

This code works fine.

```
        string url = "http://www.reciter.org/KATHEER/002002.html";
        string result = null;
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256");
        result = client.DownloadString(url);
        HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(result);
        if (htmlDoc.DocumentNode != null)
        {
            Response.Write(htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tr/td").InnerText);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Response encoding.

[Response.ContentEncoding](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.contentencoding)

Comment: I've tried to do so : Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256"); but still the same problem with "????????"

Comment: @Rawhi: Then verify the result of `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//tr/td").InnerText`

Comment: ذَلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّقِينَ . Its Arabic

Comment: Try setting the `Response.Charset` option. `charset=windows-1256`

Comment: @Rawhi: I suspect you need to wrap the entire output in valid HTML for the browser to understand. Try embedding the content in `<html><head><meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=windows-1256"><title></title></head><body> YOUR CONTENT HERE </body></html>`. If that works, try maybe just with the meta part, and see if the browser understands it.

Comment: I've tried with that but didn't work. BTW I can type arabic without any problem but  this problem faces me only when I import an html web page .

Comment: thanx I've tried to get the data using another way `WebClient` and using ur solution and it works .